# Reason for large difference in computational time for two implementations of Python string to list of unicode integer equivalents

Tags: python, time-complexity

I noticed that the latter of the following two Python implementations, which return a list of integer representations of each character in a Unicode string, requires a considerably shorter amount of computational time than the first. I’m not clear on the reason this occurs. The first implementation simply iterates through a string, converting each character to its Unicode integer representation: `[ord(c) for c in string]`. The second encodes the string and converts to a list: `list(string.encode())`.

I tested with the short string, `Hello world!`, and the latter method executed twice the speed of the initial. I then retested with this string, multiplied by 1000, ie. `Hello world!Hello world!...`, and the latter implementation executed 5 times as fast. I then recorded some data and plotted a time efficiency graph, demonstrating that both are executing in linear time, but with the latter implementation executing faster.

[image: efficiency1]

Here’s a zoomed-out graph where I sampled longer strings:

[image: efficiency2]

Comment: I would start by removing `bytearray`, it is *completely unecessary*, just do `list(string.encode())`

Comment: Oh yeah, I’m not sure why I did that originally considering the string is **already** encoded. I’ll fix that and update the question.

Comment: Okay, I’ve updated the question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, comparing the two isn't entirely that useful since they are not equivalent except for 7-bit ASCII strings:

```
>>> s = '☃'
>>> [ord(c) for c in s]
[9731]
>>> list(s.encode())
[226, 152, 131]
```

but assuming they are equivalent, you're seeing the difference between some well optimized C code and some pure python bytecode evaluation.

the `list(s.encode())` call goes through three "fast" operations:

1. UTF8 encoding (essentially a memcpy with a little bit of translation for non-ASCII characters)
2. `__iter__` over a bytes object (essentially yielding the underlying uint8s as integers)
3. [list `__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a97b1517a6b5ff22e2984b677a680b07ff0ce11/Objects/listobject.c#L2696-L2730) from sized iterable (goes down the fast pre-allocated path)

the slowness then comes down to the amount of time spent evaluating the bytecode in the list comprehension **plus** the need to dynamically rebuild the list storage as it grows (the list comprehension cannot take advantage of the size hint here and must repeatedly `LIST_APPEND` relying on `list`'s internal resizing)

```
>>> def f(s):
...     return [ord(c) for c in s]
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f1e5ade2b30, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7f1e5ade2b30, file "<stdin>", line 2>:
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                12 (to 18)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (c)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ord)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 LIST_APPEND              2
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   18 RETURN_VALUE
```

one could potentially see an optimization opportunity with common listcomprehensions by looking at the iterable and seeing if there's a size hint (assuming simple listcomps without nested iteration or conditionals) -- though as far as I know nobody has attempted such an optimization in cpython

it's altogether likely that you'd see reasonably-equivalent performance in something like pypy where the JIT may notice the size hint for the listcomp, but without access to your profiling code it's not easy for me to validate this assumption